# Algolia and WordPress search page suddenly not working, console showing "Uncaught typeError"

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins, algolia

I built a search page with WordPress & Algolia Search, and it's been working fine for a few months, but suddenly, I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'matchedWords' of undefined

The facet filters are no longer working and the search results are not being displayed.

Page in question is: https://habyts.com/activities-for-kids

I can't pinpoint anything having changed since it stopped working, so I don't really know how to fix this error.

The Algolia WordPress plugin has been updated a few days ago to 2.3.0, but I loaded the search page a few times after the update and it was working, it's only a day or so after the update that it broke and started showing the console error.

Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer from this post - https://discourse.algolia.com/t/image-size-on-instantsearch-page/1593/2

Since version 2.x, all image sizes are not returned with each search since it incurs performance issues.

To return custom image sizes other than thumbnails this code needs to be added to a plugin / functions file.

```
add_filter('algolia_post_images_sizes', function($sizes) {
    $sizes[] = 'medium'; 

    return $sizes;
});
```

Once this code has been added to functions or your own custom plugin file, you'll need to reindex everything and then your chosen custom image sizes should start to work.

Hopefully this is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'matchedWords' of undefined` error is raised because there is a field that no longer is present in your Algolia index.

From version 1.x to 2.x of the plugin, there have beens some changes and we have already seen this error once.

To solve it, you need to manually delete all the indices from your Algolia dashboard, and then trigger re-indexing of all the indices from the admin of the Algolia plugin.

In case you also did customize the autocomplete/search page template, you would need to make sure the fields used in those are still available in the data sent to Algolia.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  This would make sense, I was confused because I didn't make any code changes, and suddenly the search page was broken.

I actually 'fixed' the error by recoding my instantsearch hit template.  I removed all the code which I had relating to 'highlightResult'.  So my instantsearch hit template literally just shows the data but does not have any functionality to highlight matching search results.

I will try your suggestion of deleting my indices and will try and get the highlighting working again - will report back!

Answer (score 0):

I deleted all my Algolia Indices, and reindexed everything required, and reverted back to my old instantsearch hit template, which indeed worked again, with search highlighting working again.

One thing doesn't work though.  I was previously using `data.images.medium` to display thumbnails of each search result.  For some reason this no longer works, as in no image is displayed.  There are no console errors present and I can't figure out what's changed.

I can get `data.images.thumbnail` working to display a thumbnail with each search result.  I want however to grab a higher resolution image, which I was previously able to do using `data.images.medium`...

Any ideas?